# How do i issue commands to Telit modem using embedded c?

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on a project that requires me to access a Telit module and send AT commands.

Would love to see someone link me or paste some code that allows this. I am doing the project in embedded c.

Comment: Have a data sheet and/or app note for the modem?

Comment: Are you using [GSM 07.10](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/serial/n_gsm.txt)?  If you are not, then any general serial modem reference will work.  [chat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chat), etc.  This is still useful in *MUX* mode.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GSM LIBRARY](http://wiki.groundlab.cc/doku.php?id=gsm_library) in this library there is support of sending AT commands to Telit modules,download and cross compile it for your embedded system,examples and tutorials are provided there

Also there is [libgsmc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libgsmc/) which also have support for Telit module